# Do organisations have a pipeline per environment or should one CI/CD pipeline deliver to dev, qa and prod?

Tags: continuous-deployment

Do organisations have a pipeline per environment or should one CI/CD pipeline deliver to dev, qa and prod?

I'm trying to understand if it's beneficial to have a continous deployment pipeline with jenkins that delivers to dev, tests it, if it passes it deploys to production.

Comment: Why would you want to have separate pipelines? - that just introduces the possibility that differences can creep in.

Comment: So you are saying you would have one pipeline, that might build a project, say 3 times if it deploys to three envs (dev, qa, prod) and would test 3 times and deliver three times? e.g performing each action in the same pipeline for the number of envs you have

Answer (score 0):

IMHO one pipeline is enough.

you can minimize the environment issues by running the same test in 3 different environments (dev, qa and prod).

Jenkins implementation can be as having 3 different jobs for each environment, But Always deploy the builds and tests in order, as **dev tested -> qa tested -> prod**.

Ideally if the release build in prod is 1.0.0, then qa must have the one build upper, ie 1.0.1, and dev might have 1.0.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Valid question. I've seen and worked in environments with both. Neither is better, neither is more superior. It just depends on the need and SLAs.

If you need separation, for instance, you want the devs to have full control over the dev environments but not uat or prod, then multiple pipelines become easier than figuring out who has access to push what past what stage.

If you've got a small team and everyone knows everyone and you don't need to restrict anything then you can do one pipeline and then restrict it later as it grows.